# Not receiving notifications from WhatsApp messages

Tags: iphone, ios, messages, notifications

iPhone 7, updated to the latest iOS.

If anyone sends me a WhatsApp message, it displays as not delivered on their side, until I open the app.

On my side, I get no notification whatsoever. If I exit the app without closing it, then I receive notifications correctly, up until I lock my phone: then it goes back to not delivering, even if WhatsApp is open in the background and the phone is unlocked.

- Energy saving is disabled
- iOS Settings -> WhatsApp -> "Background App Refresh" is enabled
- Tried both on home Wi-Fi and 4G
- Battery is fully charged
- iMessages and other notifications are working just fine
- Chats aren't silenced on WhatsApp
- "Do not disturb" mode is disabled, as is any other focus mode

Why is this happening? What further steps could I take to diagnose this unexpected behavior?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings, and then Notifications and make sure WhatsApp is turned on. This will fix your problem. Also, make sure WhatsApp is up to date.

Comment: Notifications are enabled, otherwise I wouldn't receive them when the app is in background